# MySQL 5.7 JSON_EXTRACT usage with same key names in JSON array

Tags: mysql, json

I have following JSON object stored in MySQL:

```
[
  {
    "key": "user_agent",
    "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
  },
  {
    "key": "language",
    "value": "fr-FR"
  },
  {
    "key": "color_depth",
    "value": 24
  },
  {
    "key": "js_fonts",
    "value": [
      "Arial",
      "Arial Black"
    ]
  }
]
```

Can you help to SELECT for 2nd or 1st value from that JSON. Optionally where "key" is for example "user_agent". I guess that would be better as value order is not guaranteed.
I just can't really figure out, how to use JSON path as described in:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-path-syntax.html

To make it easier, here is SQL statement to create sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `components` json NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('[{\"key\": \"user_agent\", \"value\": \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; r1.0) like Gecko\"}, {\"key\": \"language\", \"value\": \"fr-FR\"}, {\"key\": \"color_depth\", \"value\": 24}, {\"key\": \"js_fonts\", \"value\": [\"Arial\", \"Arial Black\"]}]');
```

JSON_EXTRACT(components, '$[1]')  extracts second array:

```
{"key": "language", "value": "fr-FR"}
```

But it's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.. it was easier than I thought. At least to extract it:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(components, '$[1].value') FROM test;
```

returns what I want `"fr-FR"`. Or unquoted result with shorter syntax:

SELECT components->>'$[1].value' FROM test;